# Am I able to schedule something when my iPhone app is closed?

Tags: iphone

Same as the above question.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the only way would be to send the work off to a server to do the work, and have that server send a Push message to the phone when it's complete.  That would notify the user that the task has been completed, so they could then reopen the app and continue.  But running something locally on the phone while the app is closed isn't allowed by the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to background processes, the answer is currently no. This is a controversial issue with iPhone app dev at the moment as there is no way to perform background processing (afaik).